# How to plot the output of a calculation with a changing variable

Tags: plotting

The following code successfully manages to plot the cross-section, and give me the maximum depth of a weld pool, for a given set of parameters. What I would ideally like to be able to do is to plot a graph of how the the maximum depth of a weld pool varies with a parameter (ie. `v` between `0.915` and `1.5`). I think I am essentially looking to make a for loop so I can plug many different values for v in, However `Do` does not seem to work in this case. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
k = 15.75;
α = 5.79*10^-6;
T = 1015;
η = 0.6;
Q = 600;
v = 0.915;
y = 0;

g[x_?NumericQ] := 
  Quiet[ FindRoot[T == (η Q)/(2 π k Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2])*Exp[ 
                                          (-v (x + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]))/(2 α)], 
                   {z, -0.0001, -0.1, -0.0000001}][[1, 2]]]

p = Plot[ g[x], {x, -0.00001, -0.0037}, Filling -> Axis, 
FillingStyle -> Orange, AspectRatio -> Automatic]

FindMinimum[g[x], {x, -0.001}][[1]]
```

Comment: Just define your function as a function of the other parameter, for example: `g[x_?NumericQ][v_?NumericQ] :=...`, then you can express the minimum as a function of v.

Comment: Thanks Pelito, but I am unsure how I can do this as the minimum is the z at a specific x value and the v is required to calculate z and x, so won't I have too many unknowns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
g[x_?NumericQ][v_?NumericQ] := Quiet[ 
    FindRoot[ 
      T == η Q/(2 π k Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]) Exp[-v (x + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2])/(2 α)],
      {z, -0.0001, -0.1, -0.0000001}
    ][[1, 2]]
]
```

This should show how the curve `g[x]` varies with parameter `v`

```
Show[Table[
        Plot[g[x][v], {x, -0.00001, -0.0037}, PlotRange -> {0, -.0002}],
     {v, .9, 1.5, .1}]
]
```

While this computes a set of solutions for a range of values of `v` in the form `{v, minimum of g[x][v]}` . (If you wish you could create a function of `v` that computes the minimum of the curve for a given value of the parameter `v`, I leave that as an exercise to the student :-)) ).

```
minVals = Table[ 
            {v, FindMinimum[g[x][v], {x, -0.001}][[1]] }, 
         {v, .9, 1.5,.01}]
```

Once you have your minima, you can plot them with ListPlot

```
ListPlot[minvals]
```

Or you could try this

```
Plot[FindMinimum[g[x][v], {x, -0.001}][[1]], {v, .9, 1.5},
    Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Orange]
```

(Incidentally, the function plotted is the solution of the exercise left to the student :-) ).

Comment: Thanks Pelito, I think I am now getting closer to what I want (a plot of minimum z against v) by using a modified version of the third bit of code you left (I had to omit [v]).  However I couldn't get any of the other bits you suggested to run. Thanks again for getting me back on the right tracks!